# Git authenticates with wrong user

Tags: git

There are tons of questions like this, but nothing worked for me so far.  Here's what I tried:

```
git credential-cache exit
git config --system --unset credential.helper
git config --global --unset credential.helper
git config --local --unset credential.helper
```

There is no mention of the user that Git tries to log in with in `~/.netrc`

Tried running

```
git pull -v
```

But Git didn't prompt for authentication, instead it printed this:

```
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/master'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.
```

Which is obviously a lie.  The ref does exist, but it didn't fetch anything.

When I try to push to the same repository:

```
Pushing to https://github.com/{redacted}.git
remote: Permission to {redacted} denied to {redacted}.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/{redacted}/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I tried adding `[credentials]` section to `.git/config` - no changes, still authenticating with wrong user.

I don't use multi-factor authentication (however, from other places, I usually use SSH to access my repository).

`$GIT_ASKPASS` is not set, and similarly, `core.askPass`.

`~/.config/git/credentials` doesn't exist, similarly, `~/.git-credentials` doesn't exist.  `~/.gitconfig` exists, but has no mention of authentication.

Git version: 2.11.0, installed from official Ubuntu PPA.

---

Interestingly, modifying the `[remote]` in `.git/config` to have the requested user in it worked!  Still, this doesn't explain why Git didn't ask me for user, if all credential helpers and daemons are disabled.

#### Extended version

This is what I removed from `.git/config`

```
  [remote "github"]
-   url = https://github.com/{redacted}
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/github/*
```

This is what I added to `.git/config`

```
+ [credentials "https://{desired-user@}github.com/{redacted}"]
+    username = {desired-user}
+    password = {redacted}
  [remote "github"]
+   url = https://{desired-user@}github.com/{redacted}
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/github/*
```

Comment: Not a fix to your problem, but a possible alternative: https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port/

Comment: @negacao I don't want to use SSH. This is my work computer and I'm trying to access my personal repository.  I don't want to store my personal keys on work computer.

Comment: Ah - I assumed ssh was blocked.

Comment: What OS do you use on your work machine? If you are on Windows, you should look at [Git Credential Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/set-up-credential-managers).

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it's Ubuntu 17.

Comment: Note you can modify remotes with the `git remote` command rather than editing `.git/config`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yeah, but it's uncomfortable, because I don't see the effect, and I don't trust Git to not screw up something on the way. I rather just edit a file: safe and sound.

Comment: @wvxvw Git does exactly what you tell it to. As your skills and knowledge with git improve, you will be less likely to do something that screws things up. Even if you do, almost everything you do in git can be undone. This is one of its many great features.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice well, if you read my question, you may notice a contradiction there ;) Did I ever tell it to authenticate with the user it wants? Nope, not really. I actually went to great length and depth to tell it otherwise. This isn't the first time (many moons ago I tried to submit authentication related bug, but since Git project doesn't have bug tracker, and doesn't generally fix bugs, nothing happened, the bug is probably still there, I just don't have the patience to deal with "venerated gurus" working on this project.

Comment: I don't understand why you're shunning SSH. While it's understandable you don't want to copy private keys around, nothing should stop you from generating a key pair on your work computer and storing the public key on your personal remote.

Comment: @toniedzwiedz whatever my reasons are, they are not important. Authentication via HTTP is, allegedly, a feature supported by this program. If it should work, I'd like to know how, if it shouldn't... well, I'd like to hear some authoritative opinion... you know, so that I don't set up company's GitHub repos to authenticate in this way etc.

Comment: @wvxvw It sounds like the important details of your question are in the (understandably) redacted parts of the output.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice nope. What's redacted is absolutely correct. Read my edit to the question: if I put desired username into remote's URL, it works. I just want the program to prompt me for the username/password... it's supposed to be able to do this, why is this so difficult?

Comment: "if I put desired username into remote's URL" You redacted the remote's URL from the output.

Comment: "I just want the program to prompt me for the username/password... it's supposed to be able to do this, why is this so difficult?" Git itself does not handle authentication. It passes this responsibility off to some other piece of software depending on which protocol you configured for the remote.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice done. Also, I assure you. I went as far as actually reading the mess of the Git's source code responsible for authentication, and what you say is technically wrong. There are some procedures in it that handle authentication if no external provider is specified, but kill me if I know how to get those procedures to get executed. It's a terrible mess.

Comment: Debugging Git (from source—which you obviously have) is a bit of a nightmare as it's a hugely complicated thing full of weird historical artifacts. The key routines here appear to be in `credential.c` though, starting from `credential_fill`. This eventually calls `run_credential_helper`. Add some debug printf()s here to observe its behavior and see where it's getting your name.